# start "colorbox" when website is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, colorbox

I would like to load a Colorbox Inline window, when an html website opens! Does anyone have an idea how to do that? I've found some possibilities doing that with JS, when the html body loads. But I don't really know how to do that specifically with the inline window?!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using <del>Opera</del> a browser that supports HTML5 forms, all you have to do is this:

```
<input type="color" />
```

:D

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I need something different. I want to open the inline colorbox, when the website starts. I mean, when the html body loads!